# Make Bitmap image sharp

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have an application c# wpf and I use Image Bitmap.

I have a `Byte []` who contains value (0 or 255) used to draw an image in gray scale.

Example :

```
int heigth = 5;
int width = 5;
Byte[] image = new Byte[]
    { 255,   0, 255,   0, 255,
        0, 255, 255, 255,   0,
      255, 255,   0, 255, 250,
        0, 255, 255, 255,   0,
      255,   0, 255,   0, 255};
```

Corresponds to the image

[image: Image pattern]

To display this image in my application I did that :

XAML :

```
<Border Style="{StaticResource BorderStyle}">
    <Image Source="{Binding BlockPicture, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
</Border>
```

C# :

```
private BitmapSource _blockPicture;
public BitmapSource BlockPicture
{
    get
    {
        return _blockPicture;
    }
    private set
    {
        _blockPicture = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("BlockPicture");
    }
}

private BitmapSource LoadImage(int w, int h, byte[] matrix)
{
    if (matrix == null || matrix.Length == 0)
        return null;

    var format = PixelFormats.Gray8;
    var stride = (w * format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
    return BitmapSource.Create(w, h, 96, 96, format, null, matrix, stride);
}

BlockPicture = LoadImage(width, heigth , image);
```

It's work fine but when the image is displayed, it's very ugly and diffuse.

[image: Displayed image]

What can I do to have a nice picture clean and sharp ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the `BitmapScalingMode`:

```
<Image RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" />
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thank you !